# What is the most common use case for the search_api "Index Hierarchy" processor given it is limited to indexing entity ids?

Tags: search

In search_api the "Index Hierarchy" processor is [described as being](https://www.drupal.org/node/1254452) for the filtering on parent use case:

> Allows you to index hierarchical fields along with all their parents. Most importantly, this can be used to index taxonomy term references along with all parent terms. This way, when an item, e.g., has the term New York, it will also be matched when filtering for USA or North America.

However this is limited to indexing the **ids** of the reference field and the ids of the parents. Therefore it does not on its own provide the ability to search for a parent term and return all terms tagged with a child of that parent term as noted [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/3008135) and [here](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/2875576). That is an [open feature request](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api/issues/3045128).

Given these limitations what are its most common use cases? How have you used this processor to provide search options? Is it currently only useful in conjunction with [facet_api/facets](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2016/set-hierarchical-taxonomy-term-facet-using-facet-api-search-api-solr) or custom code?